# angular js directive post link can't access generated element id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I have this directive:

```
/*html, enclosed in a ng-repeat directive*/
<textarea name="alternativaHtml" id="questao_alternativa_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="alternativa.TextoHtml" data-ck-editor></textarea>

/*javascript*/
angular
    .module("fluxo_itens.directives")
    .directive('ckEditor', [function () {
            return {
                require: '?ngModel',
                link: {
                    "post": PostLink
                }
            };
        }]);

function PostLink($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
    var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(attr.id);

    ck.on('pasteState', function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
        });
    });

    ngModel.$render = function (value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
    };
}
```

the problem is that when CKEDITOR tries to create the editor instance, it can't find the element, which has its id property dinamycally generated.

Comment: I haven't use elm[0].id in the CKEDITOR.replace function because that returns me 'questao_alternativa_{{$index}}', yes, with the {{$index}} uncompiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that CkEditor wasn't able to find the element because the id of the element was not set in the DOM. So I've relied on jQuery to set de element DOM property so the CkEditor can find the textarea.
I've changed this in the PostLink function

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(attr.id);
```

to this:

```
$(elm).attr("id", attr.id).prop("id", attr.id);
var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0].id);
```

Now everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing , but you can try this :

```
<textarea name="alternativaHtml" id="questao_alternativa_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="alternativa.TextoHtml" data-ck-editor editor-id="questao_alternativa_{{$index}}"></textarea>
```

Directive

```
angular
.module("fluxo_itens.directives")
.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
        return {
            scope : {
             'editorId' : '='
            }
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: {
                "post": PostLink
            }
        };
    }]);
```

PostLink

```
function PostLink($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
var ck = CKEDITOR.replace($scope.editorId);

ck.on('pasteState', function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
    });
});

ngModel.$render = function (value) {
    ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
};
}
```

Comment: it throws: Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 21 of the expression [questao_alternativa_{{$index}}] starting at [{{$index}}].

Comment: ther is typo in binding  `<textarea name="alternativaHtml" id="questao_alternativa_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="alternativa.TextoHtml" data-ck-editor editor-id="questao_alternativa_{{$index}}"></textarea>  ` change it to    `<textarea name="alternativaHtml" id="questao_alternativa_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="alternativa.TextoHtml" data-ck-editor editor-id="'questao_alternativa_{{$index}}'"></textarea>  `

Comment: nope, it continues not working. CkEditor can't find the element. I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined